# Why would a cookie that is visible in a request in Fiddler not be available in the Request.Cookies collection?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I'm doing SSO between a .NET 2.0 site and a .NET 4.0 site using the same domain but different subdomains. Everything works fine in the development environment on a single machine but I can't get the 4.0 production site to accept the auth cookie that's generated by the 2.0 production site. These two sites are on separate servers, one running IIS 6 with only the 2.0 framework installed, and the other running IIS 7.5 with the 4.0 framework installed. I've read all the other answers to other questions that point out problems with the `<machineKey>` element and the `<authentication><forms>` element and, trust me, all of that stuff is set up properly and all 4 sites have the exact same property values for those elements.

At first I thought it was an issue with encryption, but when I took a closer look at what was going on with Fiddler I saw that the auth cookie is being correctly passed in the request, but seems to disappear at some point and is then not available in the Request.Cookies collection.

The 4.0 production site is behind a load balancer, but there are currently no other servers online in the web farm. Could the load balancer be dropping the cookie somehow? Is the cookie not added to the Request.Cookies collection because it's not a valid auth cookie? If so, why isn't it valid?

To sum up, when I execute the following on the requested page:

`HttpCookie AuthCookie = Request.Cookies.Get(".SSOAUTH");`

AuthCookie is null, even though I can see a cookie with that name in the request headers in Fiddler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authentication ticket might not be valid due to different encryption algorithms on each server. This can happen when some MS security updates are applied to one server but not the other. If the cookie does not contain a valid value it will not be added to the `Request.Cookies` collection, even though it is passed in the request.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add another option as to what might cause this.  I spent almost 2 days trying to implement Single Sign On issues between a .NET 4.0 WebForms app and a .NET 4.5 MVC app.
Like you, I was sure I had the `machineKey` and `authentication` elements configured properly. But I saw that the Forms Authentication Cookie was being sent by the browser, but not visible in Request.Cookies in my 4.5 app.

Then I found this: 
http://www.shawnmeyer.com/2013/10/sharing-forms-authentication-tickets-between-applications/

and this:
[Forms Authentication SSO - Why does User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166613/forms-authentication-sso-why-does-user-identity-isauthenticated-false)

which give 2 different ways of solving the FormsAuthentication Cookie validation failure.

Basically, you have to ensure that either the `httpRuntime`s all target the same version of the framework, or you have to add a `compatibilityMode` to the `machineKey` of the newer web app.  Either way worked for me - in the 4.5 app, change one of these:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
```

or

```
<machineKey validationKey="..."
                decryptionKey="..."
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding cookies to the logging in IIS to check it's getting through the load balancer.

Also, silly I know, but have you tried Request.Cookies[".SSOAUTH"] instead. Also look at the .count to see how many cookies it has received.

Comment: I added cookies to the log files and they are indeed getting passed through, so I guess it's not the load balancer. That seemed kind of unlikely. Trying `Request.Cookies[".SSOAUTH"]` is silly indeed, but I've seen stranger things happen, so I tried it anyway, but I had the same result. I had already checked the count and I'm even looping through and displaying all the names and values. The .SSOAUTH cookie is simply not there. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the value and it doesn't allow it to be added to the collection. Thanks for helping me eliminate one possibility.