# Request.IsAuthenticated always returning false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am working on adding login functionality to a site I am building, but after login, the Request.IsAuthenticated property always returns true.   I have searched this error and have found the same answers over and over, but those solutions are not working for me.

Code from AccountController::Login action:

```
if (response.Status == KD.Core.Enumerations.LoginStatus.LoggedIn)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
    SessionMgr.GetInstance().SetSessionValue(SessionTypes.UserId, response.UserId);

    //Have added logging here to ensure login is successful in prod.

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Code from _Layout view file where I am seeing the problem:

```
 <ul class="profile-nav">   
      @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
           <li class="active"><a href="/Account/Logout" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
      }
      else
      {
           <li class="active"><a href="/Account/Login" title="Login">Login</a></li>
      } 
 </ul>
```

The 2 previous answers I have found related to the forms authentication configuration in the web.config, but I have tried both and I am still not able to get this to work.   The code functions as expected on my development machine (ie...Logout is displayed after logging in).  The problem is that once I deploy to my prod web server the login is successful, but the Logout link is not displayed, only Login again.   I have verified that the user is being logged in as I have added code to write to a log file from the Login action (right before the RedirectToAction call) so I know it is calling SetAuthCookie, but once it hits the layout code on the subsequent redirect to my home page (Home/Index), the Request.IsAuthenticated does not ever return true so I always get "Login" link again.   The 2 things I have tried are the following changes to the web.config for forms auth:  1)  adding the "requireSSL="false"    2)  adding the domain where "contoso" = the actual domain my prod web server is hosting, but again, neither of these has fixed my issue and I'm running out of ideas.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" requireSSL="false" domain="contoso.com" />
</authentication>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well....after 2 months of ripping my hair out I finally figured this out.  The web.config at the root application level did not have the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true" flag.   Once I added that attribute, the Request.IsAuthenticated check returned true.

Hope my struggles help someone else in the future.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: But actually I have conditional redirection for particular page. I am still struggling with it. You have any idea?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to fix with the redirect?

Comment: If user logging in for first time  I am redirecting him to change password if he already changed his password then redirecting to home page.

Comment: Can you post a new question with some code and such?  I have no issues trying to help out, but flying kind of blind on this end without more info.  Send me a link to the new question and I'll look at it.

Comment: There are already such questions dynamically setti g default page for redirection after authentication but nobody has solid answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93704/discussion-between-user1011627-and-vijay-kumbhoje).

Answer (score 2):

my problem was associated with Chrome. Switching to another browser solved it immediately. The problem only occurred when using localhost on chrome. I think something to do with SSL

Comment: This is not an answer at all, it would fit better as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: i noticed that when i use incognito window in chrome it did start to work, but not in the normal chrome. i am kind of hoping this is some caching issue or something and that it will be solved automatically