# how to fetch logged in username

Tags: asp.net

My `asp.net` web application uses windows authentication. I used `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to fetch logged in username. It worked fine with localhost, but after deployment in azure cloud it is giving `null`. I tried everything like `Page.User.Identity.Name`, 
`Environment.userName`, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` all are returning null

Is there any other way to get user name?

Comment: I had a very similar issue a couple of years back and I struggled to figure out the problem...finally stumbled upon my solution after a month of fighting it....maybe it will help you too.   FYI...my issue was with forms auth, not windows auth, but still may be applicable.  Check out this SO Q&A:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091530/request-isauthenticated-always-returning-false